# I could not notice any difference in output, with and without using std::flush

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, iostream, flush

I am trying to understand the behavior of `std::flush`, but I could not notice any difference in output, with and without using `flush`, (ie) every second one number is printed in both cases.

I am using Visual Studio 2015. Does my compiler automatically flush?

How can I notice a difference?

Here's the example I took from Quora:

```
int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; ++i)
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        cout<<i<<" "<<flush; // same output when i run without flush
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can sometimes notice a missing output if you encounter a segfault right after writing without flush. In general the output will also be printed without an explicit call to flush.

Comment: thanks @churill Is that only way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does cout flush?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345226/when-does-cout-flush)

Comment: See the accepted answer on the duplicate: *"There is no strict rule by the standard - only that endl WILL flush, but the implementation may flush at any time it "likes"."*

Comment: But  how do i notice the difference? with and without using flush.

Comment: @RaHuL If you redirect the output to a file (`program > out.txt`) and then look in the file at the same time the program i running, you are more likely to see a difference. At least on posix systems. Not sure how it'll behave on Windows.