# Why is std::cerr formatting incorrectly in Clion?

Tags: c++, debugging, clion

I'm following this tutorial:
https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/basic-debugging-tactics/

The output at the end of section **Debugging tactic #2**: Validating your code flow is supposed to be:

```
main() called
getValue() called
4
```

but in CLion I am seeing:

```
4main() called
getValue() called
```

Similarly, in section **Debugging tactic #3: Printing values** the output should be:

```
Enter a number: 4
main::x = 4
Enter a number: 3
main::y = 3
4 + 3
main::z = 9
The answer is: 9
```

I'm seeing:

```
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: main::x = 4
3
main::y = 3
main::z = 9
4 + 3
The answer is: 9
```

Comment: you are interleaving the output from cerr and cout - i think the buffereing / ordering is not defined

Comment: Try to use `std::flush` after each output to `cout` to make sure it actually prints immediately. Otherwise it flushes whenever the implementation feels like it (usually when the buffer is full) or on certain blocking operations like reading from `cin`.

Comment: Possible duplicate : [When does cout flush?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345226/when-does-cout-flush)